# MapView Within LinearLayout

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-api, android-linearlayout

I'm currently working on a small application that will allow a user to be presented with a Google map upon start. The screen should display a menu bar at the top, however when I run my app on any device, the map displays across the entire layout, overlaying the menu bar.

How would I stop the fragment from overlapping my menu bar?

Here is my current layout for the activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_grey"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    map:mapType="normal"
    tools:context=".Map" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/menuSpinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:entries="@array/menu_array"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, the layout is fairly simple, just the menu bar as a LinearLayout, and the map as a fragment.

The code for this is fairly simple as well, just setting up the spinner and initializing the map.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(edu.wcu.trackerapp.R.layout.activity_map);
    // Initialize the spinner
    menu = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.menuSpinner);
    // Set up the listener for the spinner.
    menu.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    try {
        // Loading map
        initializeMap();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/**
 * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
 * */
private void initializeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    cullowLocation, 15));
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, here is a screenshot of the application running on the device, with the map code enabled. [image: screenshot of map full-screen]

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: @CarlAnderson Yes, but I didn't state it explicitly.I'll add it to the main post. How would I stop the fragment from overlapping my menu bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vertical / height part of your layout is currently

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <fragment
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And it should work if you add the weight and height to the map fragment like you did for the others.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <fragment
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Or if you use no weights

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />

    <fragment
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That got it! Much appreciated!